# Is there any web viewer in flash as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there any web viewer in flash as3? 
I want to view a web link on flash project like an iframe tag.

**I used render as html but it doesn't support all tag.**

Please advice me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `StageWebView`? [Doc here.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html)

Comment: Can i use this flash as3 project? I think its AIR library.

Comment: I thought it was flash as, on a second look I was wrong. Sorry, after fixing my filter, I believe the only option is [TextField.htmlText](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText) but that doesn't appear to support iFrames